# Twitter dataset with 125K nodes and 2M edges

Tags: data-request, social-media, network-structure

Where can I get Twitter dataset with 125K nodes and 2M edges that show relationships between users?
An edge from user i to user j means user j follows user i.

Comment: Why exactly "125K nodes and 2M edges"?

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a follower-following relationship specifically? If not, you might have more options. Specifically, you could use the Twitter StreamingAPI to collect your own data and process into a user-mention network (one could infer a follower-following relationship this way). There are also many other datasets available from which you can process in the same manner:

https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment

https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/first-gop-debate-twitter-sentiment

https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140

https://www.kaggle.com/ninzaami/a-data-set-of-tweets

http://networkrepository.com/soc-twitter.php

https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-were-sharing-3-million-russian-troll-tweets/

Answer (score 1):

[SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/), which is the standard go-to place for social media graph datasets, **had** a [twitter dataset](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/twitter7.html) with 17,069,982 nodes (users) and 476,553,560 edges (tweets).

> As per request from Twitter the data is no longer available.

Unfortunately it is no longer *officially* online. You could try to contact them, or ...

Also, the graph itself is available ([link](http://an.kaist.ac.kr/traces/WWW2010.html)).

---

You could try their other datasets, in particular the [Higgs Twitter](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/higgs-twitter.html):

- https://snap.stanford.edu/data/
- https://snap.stanford.edu/data/#twitter

---

**UPDATE**: I found a potential source on [academic torrents](https://academictorrents.com/details/276e1028b08decbf711f275a57901dbde88ca5ab). Use at your own peril.